# Set plus and int value in input type number

Tags: jquery, html

I have input type number in which I want to set value as "+31" or "+32". The code which I have used is:

```
   $(".flag_list_code").on('click', function() {//on click of a button which has class flag_list_code
       var countryCode = parseInt($(this).attr('rel')); // this returns 31,32 or numbers like this
       $('#inputPhone').val('+'+countryCode);//#inputPhone is id of input type number
   });


   <input type="number" id="inputPhone" class="phone_grat_input" >
```

But this is not working, when entering "+31" into input type number field then that works, so this should also have a way, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `type=text` instead

Comment: okay, I see I will need to use input type text for that. Thanks.